# Check if 2d array column is full

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a game class project and got stuck.

Ive been looking everywhere on how to check if any column in a  2 dimensional `Array` is full and if so, the column be completely cleared.

I'm really new to `Java` so if you can please help me out with this!

This is the code I have so far.

```
//removes filled columns - added method
private boolean removeFullCol()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){
            if(board[i][j] != occupied){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    //empty square was never found - column is full
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? is there a problem?

Comment: Don't you need some way to track each column? Here, you're iterating over every square. I'm not sure if `i` represents rows or columns, but in order to see whether a column is full, you need to keep track of how many elements in each column are filled. Here, you're returning false if any position on the board is empty, whereas you should be tracking if a column has no empty positions.

Comment: You'll need to provide more context. What is the value of `occupied`? How is this being called? What happens with the result of the `removeFullCol()` function? You just seem to be returning `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove only full cols, check by cols, but **you cant return a boolean if you want to check ALL columns**. You have 2 options:

- check a given column  (return a `boolean`)
- return first column full (return an `int`)

**First option:**

```
private boolean removeFullCol(int col)
    for (int row=0; row<board[col].length; row++) {
        // check if all are filled not sure which object is inside board...
        if(board[row][col] == null){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Second option** (returns first col full or data, -1 otherwise):

```
private int removeFullCol()
    for (int row=0; row<board[col].length; row++) {
        int filled = 0;
        for (int row=0; row<board[col].length; row++) {
            // check if all are filled not sure which object is inside board...
            if(board[row][col] != null){
                filled ++;
            }
        }

        // when finished check how many rows are filled
        if (board[col].length == filled)
            return row;

    }
    return -1;
}
```

I wrote the code *on the fly*... Let me know if any errors or doubts...